# Ubuntu installation botched up, and now it won't install

Tags: system-installation

I just received the latest Ubuntu DVD through the post. When I tried installing it, the installation abruptly stopped after just a couple of minutes. Now, when I restart my computer, I can choose between Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but when I click on Ubuntu I get a bunch of error messages that I don't understand. Is there any way that I can start the installation process from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You can.  When you get to the installation Type screen, just choose One of the three option as seen in the image below.

Keep in mind that choosing the Erase Ubuntu 13.04, and reinstall will delete all programs, and data, but since you really didn't finish the installation that shouldn't be an issue.

I would recommend using either the third option or the first option.

[image]